# Can I avoid this Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))?

Tags: c#, interop, ui-automation

This `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` comes from acquiring an instance of a (COM wrapper) UIAutomationClient.IAccessible and then calling accLocation on the object:

```
Interop.AccessibleObjectFromEvent( hWnd, idObject, idChild, out var accessible, out var accessibleChild );
int x = 0, y = 0, w = 0, h = 0;
accessible?.accLocation( out x, out y, out w, out h, child );
```

Some objects that come in on the WinEvents hook I'm listening to don't have some of the properties in the interface. I'm handling the exception...and that gets me down the road, but I would like to "discover" that the property isn't in the object rather than getting a noisy exception.

Comment: That is technically possible by rewriting the interface from the [Reference Source declaration](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Accessibility/Accessibility/IAccessible.cs,6521a9bb0a1a0adc) and applying the [PreserveSig] attribute.  Which changes the return type to *int*, a negative value indicates failure.  But, realistically, it not supporting accLocation is exceptional and you ought to get out quicker when you're not interested.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. It only occasionally happens. Most controls report a location w/o issue...and the ones that don't aren't controls my code cares about...so it's just a nuisance and no more. I think (if I'm understanding your proposal) that it may not be worth the trouble. I'll document the issue to my consumers.